# Recursively call STUFF for results in a table valued function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

This is a static query that kind of shows where I am trying to get

```
declare @Airbill VARCHAR(50) = '12345678912'
select stuff(stuff(@Airbill, 4, 0, '-'), 9, 0, '-')
```

But I need to make it more variable.  I have the following varible:

```
DECLARE @AirbillMask VARCHAR(50) = '999-9999-9999'
```

Which can (and does) change.  It is always '9's and '-'s.  But the placement of them changes.

- If `@AirbillMask` is `999-99-99-9999` my desired result would be `123-45-67-8912`.
- If `@AirbillMask` is  `999-9999-9999` my desired result would be `123-4567-8912`.

I am running [dbo.FindPatternLocation(@AirbillMask, '-')](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41997/6383) that returns a table of dash locations.

I was planning to find a way to `STUFF` the parts of the `@Airbill` into it corresponding locations to produce a calculated field of `FormattedAirbill`, but I got stuck trying to iterate down into the `STUFF` calls.

**Is there a way to call `STUFF` inside another `STUFF` call, over and over till I am out of rows?**

I feel like a recursive CTE or cross apply could accomplish this, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

NOTE: I would prefer to do this without looping, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41981/6383) to get to what I was looking for:

```
DECLARE @Airbill VARCHAR(50) = '12345678912'
DECLARE @AirbillMask VARCHAR(50) = '999-99-99-9999'

;WITH Airbill(Mask, Airbill) AS 
( 
    SELECT   @AirbillMask AS Mask, @Airbill AS Airbill
),
Position(Pos, Mask, Stuffed) AS 
( 
    SELECT   PATINDEX('%-%', Mask) AS Pos, Airbill.Mask, STUFF(Airbill.Airbill, PATINDEX('%-%', Mask), 0, '-')
    FROM     Airbill
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   Pos + PATINDEX('%-%', SUBSTRING(Mask, Pos + 1, LEN(mask))) Pos, mask, STUFF(Stuffed, Pos + PATINDEX('%-%', SUBSTRING(Mask, Pos + 1, LEN(Mask))), 0, '-')
    FROM     Position
    WHERE    PATINDEX('%-%', SUBSTRING(Mask, Pos + 1, LEN(mask))) > 0
)
SELECT  TOP 1 Stuffed
FROM    Position
ORDER BY Pos desc
```

I haven't performance tested it yet, but I do get the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a big integer so assuming this is typical you can use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) for this

```
declare @Airbill DECIMAL(38) = 12345678912


select FORMAT(@Airbill,   '000-0000-0000') AS A,
       FORMAT(@Airbill,  '000-00-00-0000') AS B,
       FORMAT(@Airbill, '00000-0000-0000') AS C,
       FORMAT(@Airbill, '#####-####-####') AS D;
```

Returns

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
|       A       |       B        |        C        |       D       |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 123-4567-8912 | 123-45-67-8912 | 00123-4567-8912 | 123-4567-8912 |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

If it isn't possible to change the mask formats to use `0` or `#` instead of `9` it can obviously easily be done at run time with a single `REPLACE` of `9` to the desired character.